# Customizing Button names in FB.ui request dialog box

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, fb.ui

I need to do gifting feature in my app. Is there a way to customize the "Send Requests" button to just "Send" in FB.ui request dialog box??[image: s]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible. Only thing you can change is the dialog title.